# jQuery Button function listening to menu open/close state change state

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this script that changes a hamburger menu button from lines to an x on click ..... I have set up a simple flag to change it's id and think this could be done better...

What I am looking to do is check the state of the menu and get the button to "act accordingly" in the form of an X (active) or the 3 lines... here is my code

```
document.querySelector( '.nav-toggle' )
  .addEventListener( "click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle( "active" );

  })

var toggle = function (funcA, funcB) {
    return function () {
        var flag = true;
        if (flag) {
            funcA();
        } else {
            funcB();
        }
        flag = !flag;
    };
};
$('.nav-toggle').click(toggle (function (){
    $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
}, function (){
    $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu( 'expand' );
}));
```

and here is the html for the button....

```
<p><a class="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>Menu</p>
```

... i know it should be relatively simple but I can't get it to work.... fyi I am currently attempting this.......

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-toggle").toggle(
     function () {
         $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'expand' );
     },
     function () {
        $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
     },

   );
```

});

but that doesn't work. Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: Syntax error at `.click(toggle (function (){` ? Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ? Is `.multilevelpushmenu` defined ?

Comment: as the top 3 lines of code came with the button and have been tested i know that bit works.... its the if/else statement that if the problem... multilevelpushmenu is indeed defined properly and both expand and collapse work as seperate methods...... it is taken from this menu http://multi-level-push-menu.make.rs/

Comment: i will have a go now

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30416633/jquery-toggle-for-two-methods-open-and-close-push-menu resolve this Question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try moving `toggle` call to within `click` event `handler` function

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu({
        onMenuSwipe: function () {
            var e = arguments[0];
            if ($(e.target).prop('tagName').toLowerCase() == 'input') return false;
        }
    });

    var toggle = function (funcA, funcB) {
        return function () {
            var flag = true;
            if (flag) {
                funcA();
            } else {
                funcB();
            }
            flag = !flag;
        };
    };

    $('.nav-toggle').click(function () {
        toggle(function () {
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('collapse');
        }, function () {
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('expand');
        })
    });
});

document.querySelector('.nav-toggle')
    .addEventListener("click", function () {
    this.classList.toggle("active");

});
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/c5EA4/256/

Comment: looks a lot better mate but now does nothing , .... the active state must be in there soemwhere perhaps , its not even opening or closing the menu now

Comment: @havingagoatit Can create stacksnippets , jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/greggy_coding/c5EA4/255/   gnore the top bit of js that's for touchscreens i think

Comment: I think it should be like this but it still doesn't work ....... $(document).ready(function() {
      $(".nav-toggle").toggle(
         function () {
             $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'expand' );
         },
         function () {
            $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
         },
        
       );

   });