# Jquery toggle for two methods open and close push menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have tried these things without the use of a toggle and they work individually. However when i do a toggle nothing works properly please help.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".nav-toggle").toggle(
         function () {
             $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'expand' );
         },
         function () {
            $( '#menu' ).multilevelpushmenu( 'collapse' );
         },

       );

   });
```

Nav toggle html simple button.

```
<p><a class="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>Menu</p>
```

Comment: `.toggle()` event is deprecated. Current `toggle()` function toggles the display state.

Comment: not sure what you mean ???

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/30194754/3639582

Comment: still doesn't make sense , can you paste your thought in a comment ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.toggle()` you are using is a jQuery event. It works like a click of button/switch. **[`toggle() (Event)`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)** event is deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9. So this is invalid now.

Current **[`.toggle()`](https://api.jquery.com/toggle/)** function changes the state of the element. Like `.show()` and `.hide()`

*<sub>Referred from **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30194754/3639582)**</sub>

---

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var state = false;
    $(".nav-toggle").click(function () {
        if(!state){
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('expand');
            state = true;
        }
        else{
            $('#menu').multilevelpushmenu('collapse');
            state = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: why does it only work for one instance of each ? I want it to be continuous

Comment: Updated the answer. I was just testing it.